# Indefinite integral with irrational exponent: $\int \frac{(2+x^{\sqrt{2}})^{3/2}}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I cannot start  to work on this $\int \frac{(2+x^{\sqrt{2}})^{3/2}}{x}dx.$

Comment: how about

$u = x^{\sqrt{2}}$ does that go anywhere?  may not be an answer,

Comment: I will try this substitution. Thanks.

Comment: I was working on 
$u = x^{\sqrt{2}}$
 - so - 
$du = \sqrt{2} x^{\sqrt{2} -1} dx= (\sqrt{2} x^{\sqrt{2}})/x dx= \frac{\sqrt{2} u}{x} dx$

Comment: you can use more subs to get something like $$\int \frac{w^4}{w^2-1} dw $$   then you do some division and use standard integrals

Comment: @Cato Thanks for the hint. I messed it up originally as had the same idea as you, then switched to $u = 2+x^{\sqrt{2}}$, then saw how to go with your second hint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $u = 2+x^{\sqrt{2}}$. Then $du=\sqrt{2}x^{\sqrt{2}-1}dx=\sqrt{2}(u-2)\frac{dx}{x}$, so $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{\sqrt{2}(u-2)}$.

$$I=\int \frac{(2+x^{\sqrt{2}})^{3/2}}{x}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \frac{u^{3/2}}{(u-2)}du$$
Now let $v=\sqrt{u}$, so $dv=\frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}$. Therefore

\begin{align*}
I&=\sqrt{2}\int \frac{v^4}{v^2-2}dv=\sqrt{2}\int \left(\frac{4}{v^2-2}+v^2+2\right)dv\\
&=4\sqrt{2}\int \frac{1}{v^2-2}dv+\sqrt{2}\int (v^2+2)dv\\
&=-4\sqrt{2}\int \frac{1}{2\left(1-\frac{v^2}{2}\right)}dv+\sqrt{2}\frac{v^3}{3}+2\sqrt{2}v+c\\
&=-2\sqrt{2}\int \frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{2}}dv+\sqrt{2}\frac{v^3}{3}+2\sqrt{2}v+c\\
\end{align*}

Now for $\int \frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{2}}dv$ let $w=\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}$, so $dw=\frac{dv}{\sqrt{2}}$
$$-2\sqrt{2}\int \frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{2}}dv=-4\int \frac{1}{1-w^2} dw=-4\tanh^{-1}(w)$$
So sub in $w=\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}$, and then $v=\sqrt{u}$ to give
\begin{align*}
I&=-4\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{v}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\sqrt{2}\frac{v^3}{3}+2\sqrt{2}v+c\\
&=-4\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{u^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{2}u^{3/2}}{3}+2\sqrt{2}u^{1/2}+c\\
\end{align*}
Now sub in $u = 2+x^{\sqrt{2}}$ to give
\begin{align*}
I&=-4\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{(2+x^{\sqrt{2}})^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{2}(2+x^{\sqrt{2}})^{3/2}}{3}+2\sqrt{2}(2+x^{\sqrt{2}})^{1/2}+c\\
&=-4\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{(2+x^{\sqrt{2}})^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\sqrt{2}(2+x^{\sqrt{2}})^{1/2}\left(\frac{8+x^{\sqrt{2}}}{3}\right)+c
\end{align*}

Comment: bravo!                   i pak bravo!

Comment: You are great mathematician

Comment: Cheers, it was Cato's hint got me going :)